# ms access 2013 form textbox as datepicker

Tags: ms-access, datepicker

Can somebody help me with adding a Date picker into a MS-access form?

I need user to pick **from** and **to date** so he can export order details within these two dates.

Comment: add a textbox in access form and select the `format property` to `long Date` or `short date` and set `Show Date Pciker` property to `for Dates`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me : )

Answer (score 1):

To add up to user10305897, in case you have issues with the date picker not showing, check the input mask property to ensure it is blank. Having an input mask prevents the date picker from showing